# How to add finishing to a zig-zag line in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, decorations, tikz-decorations

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick] (3,-0.5)--(3,-0.8)--(0.2,-0.8)--(0.2,0.8)--(3,0.8)--(3,0.5);
        \draw[thick,decoration={zigzag,segment length=2mm}] decorate{(3,-0.5)--(3,0.5)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqfku.png) is the output shown by this code:

Note that the point where the zigzag and the straight lines combine doesn't have nice finishing, as shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KirY3.png) figure.

How to achieve the correct finishing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting a `\draw` command into two is not a good idea. Try like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (3,-0.8)--(0.2,-0.8)--(0.2,0.8)--(3,0.8)--(3,0.5) decorate [decoration={zigzag,segment length=2mm}] { -- (3,-0.5)} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result (zoomed in) : [image: result]

Comment: Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your figure is composed of two paths and is therefore not closed, which is why there is this discontinuity.
The idea is to make a single closed path and using the options `pre=lineto,pre length=5pt,post=lineto,post length=5pt` just give the coordinates of the four vertices of the rectangle.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick](3,-0.8)--(0.2,-0.8)--(0.2,0.8)--(3,0.8) 
        decorate[decoration={zigzag,segment length=2mm,pre=lineto,pre length=5pt,post=lineto,post length=5pt}] {--cycle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You very much!